# Ubuntu: Using grep and find to find files that either containa string in filename or within file

Tags: ubuntu, grep, find

I have the following. What I am looking for is files that contain a string in the filename or within the file itself

```
grep -ir z50 / -s --exclude-dir=proc > grep.txt; ls -laah
find / -iname "*z50*" > find.txt; ls -laah;
```

Should the above do what I need it to? I *know* there are files that have both *z50* in the filename and within the file but not getting a hit of the files themselves.

**Context**

I have the below and am pretty sure they are filenames I'm looking at rather than the contents of a file

[image]

Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep` with option `Ril` to grap files which contain a certain string in their content

```
grep -Ril "z50" / 1> grep.txt 2> /dev/null
```

And your second line code works but you can also redirect errors by

```
find / -iname "*z50*" 1> find.txt 2> /dev/null; ls -laah;
```